# html2canvas: render same origin iframes

Tags: html2canvas

I am trying to take a screenshot of a div on my webpage using html2canvas.

In the html2canvas documentation it is stated that:

> The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets. It doesn't render iframe content either, unless the content resides under the same origin.

My div contains same-origin iframes, but the iframes dont appear in the screenshot.

My script:

```
$('#savetopdf').click(function () {

       html2canvas($('#dashboard'), {
            "logging": true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL()
                window.open(img);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but haven't been able to find a solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not implemented, any more.

I had the same issue and submitted it as a bug/feature request.

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/376

The owner of the project stated:

> **niklasvh**
>
> There is currently no support for rendering iframe's even if the reside under same origin.